# How to use Tooltip in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am new to react.
I want to have a tool tip on the label

The following serves my request

```
  <div class="sds_sp_2xl sds-cb_font--primary">
    To see Tooltip positioned on the right,
    <a role="button" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="tooltip-cb-02" class="sds-cb_tooltip">
      hover over me.
      <div role="tooltip" class="sds-cb_tooltip__content sds-cb_tooltip__content--right" id="tooltip-cb-02">Contextual helper text</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

I want to have the tooltip when we hover on the label pertained to checkbox

form

```
             <Field
               name='checkMe'
               label='check'
               component={Checkbox}
               checked={checkMe}
              {...this.checkboxActions}
            />
```

checkbox

```
export const Checkbox = (inputProps) => {
  const { input, label, checked } = inputProps
  const { name } = input

  const className = 'sds-cb_checkbox-a__input'


  return (
    <label className='sds-cb_checkbox-a' >
      <input {...input} className={className} checked={checked} type='checkbox' />
      <div className='sds-cb_checkbox-a__box' id={name} />
      <span className='sds-cb_checkbox-a__label sds_font-size--14'>{label}</span>
    </label>
  )
}
```

How do I embed it to work. So that it would be useful for the fields as well ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Refrence of React-tooltip**
This will surely help you.

```
        class Tooltip extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
         super(props)

        this.state = {
          displayTooltip: false
        }
      }

      hideTooltip=()=>{
        this.setState({displayTooltip: false})

      }
      showTooltip=()=>{
        this.setState({displayTooltip: true})
      }

      render() {
        let message = this.props.message
        let position = this.props.position
        return (
          <span className='tooltip'
              onMouseLeave={this.hideTooltip}
            >
            {this.state.displayTooltip &&
            <div className={`tooltip-bubble tooltip-${position}`}>
              <div className='tooltip-message'>{message}</div>
            </div>
            }
            <span 
              className='tooltip-trigger'
              onMouseOver={this.showTooltip}
              >
              {this.props.children}
            </span>
          </span>
        )
      }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className='container'>
            <p>Here is a <Tooltip message={'Hello, I am a super cool 
             tooltip'} position={'top'}>tooltip</Tooltip> on top.</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you should not wrap the label around the input element but set the `for` attribute to the correct id of the input. So when clicking the label the input gets focused. And to show a tooltip or start any other action use the standard javascript events `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`, set some state according to this and use this state as conditional rendering of the tooltip element:

```
<label for="someId" onMouseEnter={()=>this.setState({showTooltip:true})} onMouseLeave={()=>this.setState({showTooltip:false})}>Labeltext</label>
<input id="someId" .../>
{this.state.showTooltip && <div>Tooltip</div>}
```

This will also work when you're setting and using some redux state.